# Deleting rows within a SQL select query

Tags: sql

Sorry this is my first time writing a post and I have only started my coding journey, so I will probably not write this post very well. I've tried googling this issue but to no avail (at least not in a way I can understand it).

I've written a SQL `SELECT` query and it works, but I want to delete some rows in it before I export the data. I can only see the views of the tables and I can't create any new tables (as in I don't have permissions to do it and getting them is not an option).

From what I have read I can use the `DELETE` query, where I put my `SELECT` query after `DELETE FROM` but before the `WHERE`. In all the examples that I have seen people put in the name of the table they were deleting from after `DELETE FROM`, but as I understand I don't have any name to put there as I deleting it from a query. I wonder if I need to adjust my `SELECT` code in some way for this to work.

Does anyone have any examples or suggestions how to make it work? Whenever I try, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio seems to highlight that the problem is with my `SELECT` statement, but as I have noted, if I run it on itself it does the job. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio seems to also think that my final `WHERE` (which should apply to the `DELETE FROM`) applies to the `SELECT` query.

The alternative is I just download my select results in clear them in R, but I am trying to learn... I am happy to post the code, but my `SELECT` query is a couple of pages long, so I wonder if there is any sense....

Thanks!

---

OK here is more info, my select query is about 9 unions long, each similar to the join below (sorry, slightly edited)

```
SELECT

A.Identifier AS 'Patient ID',
A.FTID,
A.ID,
A.Clinic_Date,
A.Completed,
A.Preferred_Language AS 'Language',
A.XYZ_Name AS 'XYZ',
A.YearOfBirth AS 'Birth Year',
A.Pathway,
A.EventType,

B.Answer_Label_Knee_Joint_Treatment_En AS 'Knee Side',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En AS 'OxfordKnee 1',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Washing_Drying_En AS 'OxfordKnee 2',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Using_Vehicle_En AS 'OxfordKnee 3',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_En AS 'OxfordKnee 4',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Standing_Up_En AS 'OxfordKnee 5',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Limping_En AS 'OxfordKnee 6',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Kneeling_And_Up_En AS 'OxfordKnee 7',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Troubled_En AS 'OxfordKnee 8',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Usual_Work_En AS 'OxfordKnee 9',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Giving_Way_En AS 'OxfordKnee 10',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Household_Shopping_En AS 'OxfordKnee 11',
B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_Down_En AS 'OxfordKnee 12',
B.Left_Score AS 'OxfordKnee Score',
'Left' AS 'Knee Label Manual'

FROM ABC AS A
INNER JOIN DEF AS B ON A.ID = B.ID

WHERE A.XYZ_Name = 'Bob' 
ORDER BY A.Clinic_Date, A.Identifier, A.Completed'
```

I need to delete the rows from my query where all the the values for OxfordKnee 1-12 are NULL, so as long as a row has something for one of these values I am keeping it. I've tried to add to `AND NOT B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En = NULL` at the end of my `WHERE` clause just to try this out but it returns a completely empty table...

Comment: If you're getting more rows back than you desire, you simply add additional limiting criteria to your "WHERE" clause of your select to eliminate the unneeded rows.  Ideally each record should include the Keys and at worst you can use multiple key values to eliminate the unneeded rows...  DELETING is when you remove data from the tables themselves.  If you need to PURGE the data from the tables, then write your select statement which identifies the desired rows, then replace the select statement with the word DELETE so it goes DELETE FROM...

Comment: `SELECT {Fields}  FROM {table/View} WHERE {Set limiting Criteria}`  EXAMPLE: `SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM MyTable WHERE FIeld1='Customer' AND field2='USA'  and field3 NOT in ('Blue','Red','Green')`  IF you're yet having problems post the SQL, Sample Data and expected results. (no images) we can help you from there.  We need to understand what you've tried, what you have for data, and what your expectations are.  What extra data needs to be removed?  how do you define it? can you exclude it with the where clause?

Comment: Thanks @xQbert , I've added some more info

Comment: To do comparaison with NULL, you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.
A value can never be equals to NULL. NULL means unknow value, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @LucM ! I've tried  `B.Answer_Label_Knee_Joint_Treatment_En IS NULL AND B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En IS NULL` etc. identifies the correct rows to delete. But if I put in `WHERE A.XYZ_Name = 'Bob' AND NOT (B.Answer_Label_Knee_Joint_Treatment_En IS NULL AND B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En IS NULL)` it spits out the whole table or if I change things around it gives me the table where any row that had any NULL is deleted, rather than just deleting the rows where all the values that I selected are NULL. I guess I don't understand 'NOT'? I'll leave this for the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a where of:

```
WHERE A.XYZ_Name = 'Bob' 
AND 
(B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En is NOT NULL
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Washing_Drying_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Using_Vehicle_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_En is not null,
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Standing_Up_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Limping_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Kneeling_And_Up_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Troubled_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Usual_Work_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Giving_Way_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Household_Shopping_En is not null
OR B.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_Down_En is not null)
```

Alternatively use not exists and correlated subquery if you can define the set you don't want

```
WHERE A.XYZ_NAME = 'Bob'
  and NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT 1 
  FROM DEF Z
  WHERE Z.ID=B.ID  --uses correlation so say not those where all are not those where all oxford knees are null
    AND (Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Describe_Pain_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Washing_Drying_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Using_Vehicle_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Standing_Up_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Limping_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Kneeling_And_Up_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Troubled_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Usual_Work_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Giving_Way_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Household_Shopping_En is NULL
    AND Z.Answer_Label_Left_Knee_Walking_Down_En is NULL)
```

Comment: A way of simplifying the first one might be something like: `AND COALESCE(B.Answer_x, B.Answer_y, ...) IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Perhaps; would have to test to see if it can use indexes then.  It may simplify it for readability; but not necessarily for performance.

Comment: Thanks so much xQbert and BeRT2me ! I've tried  the first option and it has worked, and I have tried it with the `COALESCE` and it worked too. I did not try the second option as I think it will involve more code editing than the above two with respect to my query. Thanks again!